# INSERTing into one table while UPDATEing the source table

Tags: mysql

Given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `table1Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table1Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `table2Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table1Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `foo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table2Id`)
);
```

I would like to `INSERT` several rows (with the value `foo`) from `table2` into `table1`, and return to `table2`'s `table1Id` field the newly-generated primary key in the destination table. Is this possible in one query?

Comment: no. `last_insert_id()` only works on SINGLE inserts. You cannot do a multi-line insert and get all of the new IDs. You'd have to insert the rows one-at-a-time and do last_insert_id() for each one.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in a single SQL statement.

---

**UPDATE**

After re-reading the question, I see I missed the boat... the rows being inserted into `table1` are *FROM* `table2`. So that bit of my answer about "inserting" into table2 was way off.

If you have an unique key on `foo` in table2, then you could use an AFTER INSERT trigger on table1, and the trigger could perform an update of table2. (The value of the auto_increment `table1id` column is availabe in an AFTER INSERT trigger.

As another alternative, you might consider adding the `table2id` column to `table1`, and inserting the value from table2 into table1... then you could update table2 from that.

But bottom line, to answer your question, no, it's not possible to accomplish what you describe using a single SQL statement.